# Angular 4.3 HttpClient Console Error

Tags: angular

While incorporating with the new HttpClient module in Angular 4.3, I get a console error when getting a single record from a REST api.  I don't receive any linter errors in the ide,  the page renders and the variables are displayed.  Am I declaring the wrong variable type?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
          My name is {{hero.name}} and my id is {{hero.id}}
  `})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOne() {
    this.http.get<Hero>
      ('http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/heroes/23')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.hero = data;
      });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOne();
  }
}
```

returns: My name is Bombasto and my id is 13

with the console error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.hero.name')
```

while the first key generates an error, the second doesn't (e.g. no error for hero.id).  If i switch the order(hero.id is first so the output is "my id is 13 and my name is Bombasto), i get the error for hero.id and not hero.name.

As the page renders, I could ignore the console errors and move on. I am trying to learn by stripping the code down to the bare minimum to understand how it works, and I don't want to develop any had coding habits.

Also, the same example with getAll() works with no errors:

```
heroes: Hero[];
getAll() {
        this.http.get<Hero[]>
          ('http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/heroes')
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.heroes = data;
          });
      }
```

thanks,

Comment: Try initializing hero or adding *ngIf="hero" to your node.

Comment: both options worked to clear the error.  Alternatively, i can also `.subscribe (data=>{this.hero.id = data.id; this.hero.name=data.name;} to avoid the error, but was trying to minimize my code.  thanks,

Comment: *ngIf="hero" appears to be the cleanest answer as it doesn't flash the initialized variables on the screen before the HTTP call comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Before the HTTP call comes back, `hero` is undefined.  Angular4 has a nice template tester for this.  If you change `{{hero.name}}` to `{{hero?.name}}`, angular will only try to access `.name` once it has verified that `hero` exists.

You'll also want to do the same with `{{hero.id}}`, changing it to `{{hero?.id}}`

Comment: Are you suggesting that Angular no longer crashes and burns when you mistakenly ask for something that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: It will crash and burn if you don't put that `?` in there.  `{{hero.name}}` will give the "hero is not an object" error, unless you put `{{hero?.name}}`, which is essentially the equivalent of `{{hero && hero.name}}`

Comment: The only reason I asked is that before, nothing would render. According to OP, Angular is complaining but doing it anyway.

Comment: Neither {{hero?.name}} nor  {{hero && hero.name}} cleared the console error.  And wolfhoundjesse is correct, the page renders fine. Angular is "complaining but doing it anyway."

Comment: Is it the same error? Or this time is it for `_co.hero.id`?

Comment: its the same error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.hero.id')`

Comment: right, so it's different, in that it doesn't reference hero.name, but instead references hero.id.

Now change `{{hero.id}}` to `{{hero?.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

The Elvis operator `?.` will fix the errors, but depending on how quickly the data loads you may notice that at first, the text will be there with blank spaces: `My name is  and my id is` (you'll definitely notice this if you ever work with large amounts of data or pulling from an external server).  An alternative solution is to hide the entire chunk of text until `hero` has a value, using `*ngIf`:

```
template: `
    <span *ngIf="hero">My name is {{hero.name}} and my id is {{hero.id}}</span>
`
```

This will also avoid the errors you're getting, since the contents of the element aren't loaded at all until the condition is true.